# Кука приходит на клиент, но не проставляется

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookie

Суть такова:
Есть 3 ручки на бэке, все три отправляют куку на клиент

1я ручка авторизации по коду, который приходит на почту(без пароля):

```
const dbInstance = new WishListFileDatabase(databasePath)
    dbInstance.authoriseUserViaToken(token)
        .then((data: string) => {
            res.cookie('auth-token', data, {domain: domainUrl, maxAge: cookieAge, httpOnly: false})
            res.status(200).send()
        })
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.error(err)
            res.status(500).send(err)
        })
```

2я - ручка авторизации по логину и паролю:

```
    const dbInstance = new WishListFileDatabase(databasePath)
    dbInstance.authoriseUserByLoginAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data: string) => {
            console.log(`User: ${email}, has logged in`)
            res.cookie('auth-token', data, {domain: domainUrl, maxAge: cookieAge, httpOnly: false})
            res.status(200).send()
        })
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            res.status(500).send(err)
            console.log(err)
        })
```

3я - ручка подтверждения почты, решил, что после подтверждения почты было бы не плохо сразу проставить куку и редиректить на необходимую страницу.

```
const dbInstance = new WishListFileDatabase(databasePath)
    dbInstance.emailConfirmation(confirmationCode)
        .then((data: string) => {
            res.cookie('auth-token', data, {domain: domainUrl, maxAge: cookieAge, httpOnly: false})
            res.status(200).send('Email confirm successfully')
        })
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.error(err)
            res.status(500).send(err)
        })
```

переменные domainUrl и cookieAge подтягиваются из конфига.
Собственно проблема в том, что в 1м и 3м случае кука проставляется отлично без проблем. А вот во втором случае она на клиент приходит, однако в апликэйшн не записывается.
Может я просто чего то не вижу, какую то очепятку.
Спасибо!

Comment: что в переменной data во "второй ручке"?

Comment: строка. точнее - кука, и я вижу ее в запросах на клиенте. но она не проставляется